# Hide payment logos for certain product categories

Tags: category, layout, catalog

I want to hide the payment logos for 1 product category. I've taken a look and they're in a block in the `local.xml`, but as far as I know XML doesn't like if statements.

Is there any way of doing it on PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Custom Layout Update` field in the `Custom Design` tab when editing a category if you want to add custom XML.

If you want to keep this in your `local.xml`, the category controller loads a handle called `CATEGORY_` followed by the category ID. So you could basically do the following:

```
<CATEGORY_IDHERE>
   <reference name="left">
        ...remove my icon...
   </reference>
</CATEGORY_IDHERE>
```

Comment: Is the category ID the numeric one?

Comment: Yes that would be the one. If you edit a category, you will see the title is "CATEGORY_NAME (ID: CATEGORY_ID)"

Comment: so would it look like `<category_17>`?

Comment: That would be <CATEGORY_17>, capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiet way in PHP is to check the product category, 
Say that the category name is 'cat1' so, your block will look like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) :
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
if ($cat->getName()==="cat1"):


// Set div style=display:none to hide it
div class="payment-logos" style="display:none !important;"

endif; // End if
endforeach; // End foreach
```

Have fun !!

Comment: Loading objects unnecessarily will slow down a store in no time. To avoid.